# why Catch block fail to catch Prisma Error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

Hi I Want to know why the try-Catch doesn't catch the **PrismaClientInitializationError**:
Even if the function is inside the try-catch block.
I want to know why the error it wasn't cached, not about how to solve the error
This is My Code

```
try
{
    await prisma.user.createMany({
        data : Array.from({length : numberOfUsers}, () => ({
            fullName : faker.internet.userName(),
            email : faker.internet.email().trim().toLowerCase(),
            password : faker.internet.password().substring(0, 4).toLowerCase().trim(),
            phone : faker.phone.number(),
            verified : true,
        }))
    });

}
catch(error){
    console.log("Error", "Wiiiiii");
}
```

and this is the output

```
PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid `prisma.user.createMany()` invocation in
/mnt/c/Users/khalid/Desktop/bringoria-hunt/backend/prisma/seed.ts:33:20

  30
  31
  32 async function createUsers(numberOfUsers : number){
→ 33    await prisma.user.createMany(
error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:11
   |
10 |     provider = "mongodb"
11 |     url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   |
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `~/backend/prisma/seed.ts` and is that the env URL `DATABASE_URL` cannot be found. This has nothing to do with the first code block you showed. You'd need a `try/catch` around the `await` function in your `createUsers` method in `~/backend/primsa/seed` to catch the error correctly

Comment: but shouldn't the error be catched anyways?

Comment: Why should they be already caught?

Comment: So, there is an error that comes from what is inside the try { ... }. I do not understand why the program does not console.log as expected, even if the error comes from prisma internals.

Comment: Or maybe the initialization happens before the try { ... } is that what you mean?